# Check which Locale is running in Android

Tags: android, locale

How do I programmatically check which Locale is running currently on the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Locale.getDefault().toString()`
or
`context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName()`

both will return strings

Comment: @Chanda: Will both return the same String? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: The would return the same string since `Locale.getDisplayName()` is the same as `Locale.getDisplayName(Locale.getDefault())`. Details here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html